# SVN: Add a set of Subdirectories but only specific files

Tags: jenkins, svn

I have a subfolder with a lot of subfolders in it. Each subfolder has an settings.ini file in it. Every once in a while a new subfodler with a Ini-File and a lot of other files and subirectories are added, i want to automatically add and commit it via jenkins, but only the folder and the ini.

```
C:/Program Files (x86)
-horst
--kevin
---settings.ini
--georg
---settings.ini
--heinz
---settings.ini
--herbert
---settings.ini
...
```

I tried:
`svn.exe --quiet --password %SVNPW% --username "%SVNUSER%" add --depth infinity --parents "C:/Program Files (x86)/horst/*/settings.ini"`

But this is not working, I get the message:

`svn: E720123: Can't make directory 'C:/Program Files (x86)/horst/*'`

Is there another solution, what am I doing wrong

regard Nils

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick

```
cd "C:/Program Files (x86)/horst"
dir /B /S settings.ini  > file_list.txt

%SVN%  --quiet --password %SVNPW% --username "%SVNUSER%" add --depth infinity --parents --targets file_list.txt
```

I created a list of targets I want to add and let SVN crawl it.

Nils